# How to add button on each MediaWiki article?

Tags: php, javascript, mediawiki

I would like a button to appear on each article on my MediaWiki site, to make it easy to flag articles that should be reviewed.

When the button is clicked it should add the category "review", and if the category is already there, it should remove the category from the article.

**Question**

Is this possible first of all? And if, does anyone know of code that is close to this, that I can modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaWiki comes with an extension that does just that: Flag revisions of pages including multiple flag settings and modes for different sets of users.

[http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:FlaggedRevs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aExtension%3aFlaggedRevs)

I quote:

> FlaggedRevs is an extension ... that allows a wiki to monitor the changes that are made to pages, and to control more carefully the content that is displayed to the wiki's readers. Pages can be flagged by certain "editors" and "reviewers" to indicate that they have been reviewed and found to meet whichever criteria the wiki requires. Each subsequent version of the page can be "flagged" by those users to review new changes. A wiki can use a scale of such flags, with only certain users allowed to set each flag. ...

Comment: I think this is not what's being asked for. Flagged revisions are to flag a revision as “correct”, so that it can be displayed to visitors. The question asks for a way to flag page as problematic instead.

Comment: Oh I see. It's not really clear by the description of the extension if it only works for approving/rating revisions ... Hmm, I'll have a look some more and edit the answer in case I find something ...